# How to create .EXE file in python using cx_freeze

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have one application developed in python 3.2, which has inbuilt modules(ex: Tkinter, matplotlib, openpyxl), user defined modules & classes(ex: draw_graph, generate_report), icon files, log file, .csv, .docx etc. I am running this application from script(ex: testapplication.py)

I have setup file as

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
exe = Executable(
    script=r"C:\Python32\testapplication.py",
    base="Win32GUI",
    )

setup(
    name = "TESTApp",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "An example",
    executables = [exe]
    )
```

Now I want to create a exe file of this application. can anyone please suggest me a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is what you need to do. For starters, change `script=r"C:\Python32\testapplication.py"` to `script=r"testapplication.py"`

Then, put ALL the files to need to convert into `C/python32` including the setup file. Then what you wan to do is get your command line up, and type the following commands: (assuming that you're cx_freeze file is named setup.py):

```
cd
cd python32
python setup.py build
```

And then you should have a build folder in that directory containing the exe file.